# Is it possible to get a map for all treasure chests?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I bought all of the maps at the Book store, but I still sometimes come across treasure chests not on my map.  Is there just not a map for these chests, or have I just not found it yet?

Comment: If the chests are not on the map then you don't have all the maps.

Comment: Are you sure they are treasure chests? There are other chests that contains bomb crafting materials. Those chests don't show up on the map and I believe their contents get repopulated unlike treasure chests. Did you also get the maps for Cappadocia (they can only be bought in Cappadocia afaik)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Assassins Creed: Revelations, there are essentially 2 types of chests.

**Treasure Chests**

[Treasure chests](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Treasure_chests) can be found hidden throughout the game, in all different parts of Constantinople and Cappadocia. The locations of these chests can be found either by searching the city manually, or by purchasing [maps](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Book_shops#Maps) at [Book Shops](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Book_shops). These chests reward Ezio with money. \

There are 12 maps that can be bought, and I've included their prices:

1. Imperial District Map 1:    949
2. Imperial District Map 2:    1,380
3. Galata Map 1:   828
4. Galata Map 2:   1,323
5. Bayezid District Map 1: 874
6. Bayezid District Map 2: 1,495
7. Constantine District Map 1: 897
8. Constantine District Map 2: 1,633
9. Arsenal Map:    1,415
10. Cappadocia Map 1:  1,104
11. Cappadocia Map 2:  1,760
12. Ishak Pasha's Memoir Map:  12,075 (note this map is only available after collecting 25 [Animus Data Fragments](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Animus_data_fragments))

**Bomb Ingredients Chests**

These chests are unmarked on the map, and contain supplies used to make bombs. As stated on the [wiki](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Treasure_chests#Valuable_items):

> For chests in Constantinople, they often contained bomb ingredients, replacing trade items.

Thus assuming you have actually bought all of the treasure maps listed above, the chests you are likely finding are Bomb Ingredient chests.

A brief discussion on these unmarked chests can be found [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/628358-assassins-creed-revelations/61683221).